# Clicking any Settings menu in Google Keyboard causes crash

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

> 12-12 15:57:18.830 9337-9337/com.android.inputmethod.latin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: com.android.inputmethod.latin, PID: 9337
>                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.inputmethod.latin/com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.latin.preference.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Preference xml file not specified
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2649)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2710)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1461)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6095)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Preference xml file not specified
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.libs.framework.preference.CommonPreferenceFragment.onCreate(PG:26)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2336)
>                                                                                    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:949)
>                                                                                    at android.app.BackStackRecord.setLastIn(BackStackRecord.java:860)
>                                                                                    at android.app.BackStackRecord.calculateFragments(BackStackRecord.java:900)
>                                                                                    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:728)
>                                                                                    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1578)
>                                                                                    at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:371)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6695)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2710) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1461) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6095) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Any idea what this crash is about and how I would be able to fix it? What is the preference xml's purpose and how can I fix this?

Comment: You do not have a preferences.xml for the preference views?  If not where do you have the XML for them

Comment: Did you get updated Google keyboard from AOSP keyboard by OTA ?